# E-mail verification button vs link

Tags: email, browser, registration, user-registration, email-verification

My company is redesigning one of our e-mail verification template.
We would like to use a "Button" which would act as a link to verify the e-mail address.
Theres a lots of site where the verification URL is included below the button for the case "if the button is not working, copy this link to your browser".

**In which cases can the writen link be needed?** I personaly never experienced a problem with a button, so I would drop it from the e-mail (it looks bad), but i'm interested what you think about it.

Thank you,
Ákos

Comment: It's more on topic on UX than on Stack Overflow. Anyway: for security reasons any **interaction** with an HTML e-mail may be **disabled** (even directly clicking the link may not work). User may have some kind of visual impairment and she may read e-mail with a **screen-reader**. Enough?

Comment: This [answer](http://ux.stackexchange.com/a/68450) might help you.

Comment: this is not the question for StackOverflow, it's [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).